# to edit queryset in python django

Tags: python, django

```
total_trans_today = Addfuel.objects\
                           .filter(date_created__year=datetime.today().date().year,
                   date_created__month=datetime.today().date().month,
                   date_created__day=datetime.today().date().day)
```

In above queryset, it gives data for today or day wise,
how do i edit it to get data for month or month wise.
Please help

Comment: Just remove `date_created__day=datetime.today().date().day` line.

Comment: just keep this param `date_created__month=datetime.today().date().month` in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the query in one of the following way

Following query will return the data for current year, current month

```
total_trans_today = Addfuel.objects.filter(
    date_created__year=datetime.today().date().year,
    date_created__month=datetime.today().date().month,
)
```

Following query will return the data which was created in current month irrespective of the year

```
total_trans_today = Addfuel.objects.filter(
    date_created__month=datetime.today().date().month,
)
```

To order a queryset use `order_by` in ascending order, use the following query

```
total_trans_today = Addfuel.objects.filter(
    date_created__year=datetime.today().date().year,
    date_created__month=datetime.today().date().month,
).order_by('date_created')
```

To order a queryset in descending order, add a `-` sign in following

```
total_trans_today = Addfuel.objects.filter(
    date_created__year=datetime.today().date().year,
    date_created__month=datetime.today().date().month,
).order_by('date_created')
```

> [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: thank you sir, that was very kind of you, just one query that what if i want to display the results in descending order? for eg its showing fom 1st jan to 31st jan, but i want that it should display from 31st to 1st.